# Using VBA in Word, How to clear/update/change/reformat the Style of a Footer

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I am trying to insert a footer into each page of a Word Document. Sometimes the following code works, others it doesn't. The issue: The Footer style is defaulting to a style such as Header1 or Header2, or Body Paragraph style. How can get the code to clear/change and/or update the default style in the footer, so I can just insert the text in the code into the footer w/o the formatting issues I've been getting?

```
Sub FooterInsertion()

    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim objRange As Word.Range
    Dim myTable As Table
    Dim i As Long
    Dim f As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim auth As String

    auth = InputBox("Type in the Number")
    If auth = "" Then Exit Sub

'    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objWord = Application
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    objDoc.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False


    For i = 1 To objDoc.Sections.Count
        With objDoc.Sections(i)

            For f = wdHeaderFooterPrimary To wdHeaderFooterFirstPage
                Set objRange = .Footers(f).Range
                s = objRange.Text
                With objRange
                    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
                    With .Font
                        .Name = "Arial"
                        .Size = 9
                        .Bold = vbTrue 'wdToggle

                    End With
                    .Text = "CONFIDENTIAL INFORMATION                                                                                  CW" & auth & Chr(11) & _
                            s & Chr(9)
                    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                    .Fields.Add Range:=objRange, _
                                Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
                                PreserveFormatting:=True

                End With


            Next f
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a defined style rather than directly formatting the footer text...

```
Set objRange.Style="UseYourFooterStyleNameHere"
```

Or you can modify the existing default style for the footer:

```
Dim objStyle as Style

Set objStyle=objDoc.Styles("UseTheExistingStyleNameHere")

With objStyle
    With .Font
        .NameAscii="+body" ' Uses the document's default body text font
                            ' and the .Font.Name will appear as that font's name
                            ' (e.g., "Calibri", or "Arial", or ...)

        'or hard-code with: .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Size=9
        .Bold=vbTrue
    End With
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment=wdAlignParagraphLeft
End With

Set objStyle=Nothing
```

Of course, if the default footer style is used elsewhere for other text, you'll change those places, too.